# Collecting trace info of SQL Server 2005 using SQL Server 2008 R2 profiler

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a vs2005 application that uses SQL Server 2005. I was trying to collect the SQL trace generated by the application while executing. For collecting the trace I've connected to SQL Server 2005 through SQL Server 2008 R2 Profiler. To my disappointment I found no trace data were collected by the SQL Server 2008 R2 Profiler.

I'm using Win 7 64-bit

Am I missing anything ? Can anyone advise on this ?

Comment: You're going to need to tell us exactly what you did. Are you sure you're connecting to the right server? I have the 2012 tools installed on my machine and Profiler works fine against 2005.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might possibly be mistaking a server side trace and SQL Server Profiler which perform very similar functions but work slightly differently and store data in different places.

Show us your code on how you started the trace, or tell us what steps you took.  You could also look at the following:

Server Side Trace:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72363/

Profiler (not recommended unless you are collecting a small amount of data):
http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ht/trace.htm

Is the problem that when you start up SQL Server Profiler and start collecting data nothing populates the screen?